# While loop returning data

Tags: php, loops

In the code below, I'm pulling all upcoming training classes from my database. I'm checking to see if the `endDate` has passed and I'm also checking if the `status !='2'`

I want this to return the 4 most recent results. It works fine until `status`does =2. I understand that the loop is technically running 4 times, but only displaying the results with `status !='2'`

How can I change this so that if `status = '2'` the loop will continue until it finds 4 results that meet the criteria?

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$count = 0;
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * from training ORDER BY startDate ASC');  
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            while($count <= 4 && $row = $sth->fetch()) { 
                if($row['endDate'] > $today && $row['status'] != '2') {?>
                    <li>
                    <img class="post_thumb" src="/images/img.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="post_description">
                        <small class="details">
                            <?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['startDate'])) . ' - ' . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['endDate'])) ?>
                        </small>
                        <a class="post_caption" href="/register.php?course_id=<?php echo $row['courseId'] . '&id=' . $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <?php }
                    $count++;
                    }
                ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must put the `$count++` inside the `if` loop, otherwise it will always get incremented.
As in:

```
<?php
$today = date("Y-m-d");
$count = 0;
$sth = $dbh->query('SELECT * from training ORDER BY startDate ASC');  
        $sth->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
            while($count <= 4 && $row = $sth->fetch()) { 
                if($row['endDate'] > $today && $row['status'] != '2') {?>
                    <li>
                    <img class="post_thumb" src="/images/img.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class="post_description">
                        <small class="details">
                            <?php echo date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['startDate'])) . ' - ' . date("m/d/Y", strtotime($row['endDate'])) ?>
                        </small>
                        <a class="post_caption" href="/register.php?course_id=<?php echo $row['courseId'] . '&id=' . $row['id'] ?>"><?php echo $row['title'] ?></a>
                    </div>
                    </li>
                <?php 
                $count++;
                }
            }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can break out out of the loop, if its four

```
while($row = $sth->fetch()) { 
        ....
        if($row['status']=='2' && $count >="4") break;
        $count++;
}
```